# Only select the first element, regardless of type

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to apply a style ONLY to the absolute first element of a container, if it is an h1, h2, or h3... But, if in the same page there are different headings (h1, h2, h3), only the first one should inherit the styling.

For eg.

```
<div class="container">
   <h2>I want to change this</h2>

   <p>....</p>
   <h3>But not this!</h3>
   <h2>and not this!</h2>
</div>
```

I tried to use this code:

```
.container h1:first-of-type, .container h2:first-of-type, .container h3:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem is that both the first H2 and H3 are affected by this code.

I even tried this... but without success:

```
.container > h1:first-of-type, .container > h2:first-of-type, .container > h3:first-of-type {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try my code now...this will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now again try this,i think this is wht you are looking for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container > h1:first-child{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container > h2:first-child  {
    background-color: orange;
}
.container > h3:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <h2>I want to change this</h2>

   <p>....</p>
   <h3>But not this!</h3>
   <h2>and not this!</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what the asker is already using, and exactly what they don't want.

Comment: Yeah, that looks better.

Comment: OP said  _"regardless of type"_, can simplify to `.container > :first-child`

Comment: @blonfu: The question title contradicts the question body, which says "if it is an h1, h2, or h3..."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you think. But you can try to undo the changes you made by using the [sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` in every possible combination.

This is rather long CSS code. You can make this more comfortable by using less. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/mAmQoG)

```css
.container > h1,
.container > h2,
.container > h3 {
  background: red;
}
.container > h1 ~ h1,
.container > h2 ~ h1,
.container > h3 ~ h1,
.container > h1 ~ h2,
.container > h2 ~ h2,
.container > h3 ~ h2,
.container > h1 ~ h3,
.container > h2 ~ h3,
.container > h3 ~ h3 {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h2>I want to change this</h2>

   <p>...</p>
   <h3>But not this!</h3>
   <h2>and not this!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This is if you don't assume that the first h1, h2, h3 is in fact the first child of .container. Based on the given HTML and the phrasing used in the question, though, I would think that a perfectly reasonable assumption to make...

Comment: The solution of Ganesh works fine for me. Thank you anyway